# How to set a value to a global variable inside a function in javascript/angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, functional-programming, global-variables

Well, I need to use a variable in different angular controllers or any function, which I can do, but in this particular case I'm getting the value of one of those variables  from a service or a function, how you want to call it, this is the code

```
//global variable userdata
userdata = {};

ng.tcts.service('$user', function($http, $q, $window, $boots){
return{

    login: function(data){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:ng.api+'/log/in',
            data:{
                    data:data
                },
            headers:{'Content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}        
        }).success(function(response, status, headers, config){
            if(response.success){
                console.log(response);
                //userdata assignation
                userdata = response.data;  
                deferred.resolve([response.respnum, response.success, response.report, response.data]);
            }
            else{
                deferred.resolve([response.respnum, response.success, response.report, response.data]);
            }
        }).error(function(response, status, headers, config){
            deferred.reject([response.respnum, response.success, response.report]);
        });
        return deferred.promise;        
    }

);
```

As  you can see I'm asigining userdata the value of response.data inside the success function , when I use it in the function environment it works , the assignation works fine, but when I try to use it outside of it, the object is empty, I hope you can help me with this, thx

Comment: How are you calling it outside?

Comment: What do you mean, the variable or the service?, the service like thisdata = {
  username: $scope.username,
  password: $scope.password
  };
  var promise = $user.login(data);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all you need to do is make a service that gets and set the user data and the data is kept inside the service. Then you make a method that returns that data and you can inject it into any controller in your app.

```
app.service('userData',function(){
var data;

this.get = function() {
    // do your ajax call to get your user data and in the response data = response;
}

this.data = function() {
    return data;
}
});
```

then in any controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope,userData) {
    // you can access it with this userData.data();

    // or set it to a $scope var

    $scope.userData = userData.data();
}
```

Making a global variable isn't how you use Angular you can create a service that you then inject into your controllers so multiple places can talk to that data or you can set it to a $rootScope var and then reference it in any controller. NEVER create a global variable and reference it in your controller though. This is how you end up with memory leaks in Angular.

Comment: But in this case I would have to make a call each time I need data of the user to the server, and that's what I want to avoid

Comment: no you wouldn't you get the data once assign it to data variable in the service and then you just use userData.data() to point to it. Trust me i do this in my app.

Comment: So you are saying that this will cut the cheese, or am I doing it wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/FoKeHFu0y2QCOIk0jzKy?p=catalogue

Comment: almost this is more like it http://plnkr.co/edit/SaewaPKIGV37KHE83Fiu?p=catalogue

Comment: @btm1 where do you call getdata()? I have to do it in every controller...otherwise data() is undefined...also I cannot assign like this "$scope.userData = userData.data()", because at the time of assignment data() is not returned yet from the server...

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear on what your question is. If you are simply hoping to call this service from any controller and get the value of `userdata`, then just resolve your promise with the `response.data`.

So in your service:

```
deferred.resolve(response.data);
```

*or any other response items you need

And in the controller:

```
$user.login(payload).then(function(userData){
   console.log(userData);
});
```

***If you want maintain this data after you have already made a request to the server***, you could also just set somewhere in a *variable* (as @btm1 suggested) of a service, something like in the example below.

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vIfP5v?p=preview)

Comment: What I need is to assign the response.data value to the userdata object

Comment: but I'm only calling it once, that's the why of the global variable, just cathing it once and use it all the session without making requests everytime the data is used

Comment: yes, then the second part (see bold) would be the way to go

Comment: I' don't get you could you explain me with an example, I made this plunkercan you tell me if that's what you mean http://plnkr.co/edit/eEa9Vef2UhR1WGgUV5ZN?p=info

Comment: Here is an example using movie info from a web service: http://plnkr.co/edit/3xML1Z4Uuxxp0yinRTPW?p=preview

Comment: Do you think this structure can do it? http://plnkr.co/edit/FoKeHFu0y2QCOIk0jzKy?p=catalogue

Comment: I would say no. Theres some things fundamentally wrong with what your doing in your newest plnkr. (like setting `response.data = data` when your calling your returned payload `response`. I would suggest trying to understand my example more thoroughly and fit it to your request.

Comment: could you mark this correct if this answer helped or answer your question?

Comment: This answer isn't correct.  Yes you're saving the movie to the service but you should never save anything to a service as a method in the service this.movie ... you should just create a variable in the service movie and set movie equal to the response and then create another method to return the data. This way the data in private to the service and is not automatically included every time the service is injected into a controller.

Comment: good point. credit deserved where credit is due